# Difference between Artificial Intelligence and Machine Learning?

Tags: machine-learning, artificial-intelligence

What exactly is the difference between Artificial Intelligence (AI) and Machine Learning (ML). 
According to Wikipedia I found :

**Artificial Intelligence**

> In computer science, Artificial intelligence (AI), sometimes called
>   machine intelligence, is intelligence demonstrated by machines, in
>   contrast to the natural intelligence displayed by humans and other
>   animals. Computer science defines AI research as the study of
>   "intelligent agents": any device that perceives its environment and
>   takes actions that maximize its chance of successfully achieving its
>   goals.

**Machine learning**

> Machine learning (ML) is the scientific study of algorithms and
>   statistical models that computer systems use to progressively improve
>   their performance on a specific task. Machine learning algorithms
>   build a mathematical model of sample data, known as "training data",
>   in order to make predictions or decisions without being explicitly
>   programmed to perform the task.

But isn't AI also creating Mathematical Models to ***take actions that maximize its chance of successfully achieving its goals*.** ?

Comment: "If it is written in Python, it's probably machine learning If it is written in PowerPoint, it's probably AI."

Comment: ML is a branch of AI

Comment: There are quite a few "definitions" available on line and in hard-copy literature.  Please research more than one pair before presenting here -- otherwise, you open a broad discussion topic.  You've found the descriptive flaw in this author, but the narrowing of AI to ML is not controlled by this one person.

Comment: Machine Learning is a subset of Artificial Intelligence. Similarly Deep Learning is subset of Machine Learning.

Answer (score 6):

The fundamental difference lies in their approaches. AI is a general term used for the field which is trying to mimic human behaviour and its intelligence. Any method or approach which is capable of doing this comes under AI.

Machine learning is a subset of AI which implements AI by learning patterns from data and then make predictions based on these patterns.

Answer (score 0):

> Machine Learning is a subset of Artificial Intelligence.
>   ML is powering much of the development in the AI field.

**Artificial Intelligence**
Artificial Intelligence can be loosely interpreted to mean incorporating human intelligence to machines.
Whenever a machine completes tasks based on a set of stipulated rules that solve problems (algorithms), such an “intelligent” behavior is what is called artificial intelligence.

**Machine Learning**
Machine learning can be loosely interpreted to mean empowering computer systems with the ability to “learn”.
ML is a science of designing and applying algorithms that are able to learn things from past cases. If some behavior exists in past, then you may predict if or it can happen again. Means if there are no past cases then there is no prediction.
Things like Image Recognition and Natural Language Processing is great examples of ML.

Answer (score 0):

in nowadays, AI is just using machine learning and even deep leaning methods to solve some problems, but actually machine learning is a subset of AI. so why people always say AI instead of ML? The word AI is more attractive and imagination for ordinary people.

Answer (score 0):

Artificial Intelligence is a superset of Machine Learning. This means that everything that is Machine Learning is also Artificial Intelligence.

Artificial Intelligence is generally accepted as an entity that acts in a rational way.

This can arguably be as simple as a thermostat where it will turn on the Air Conditioning when the temperature gets too high.

Machine Learning is where the entity uses data to inform its decisions and learn.

An example would be where a computer looks at all of the driving records of everyone in the world. It then takes all of that into account and then does statistical analysis and then finds that men under the age of 25 who smoke are 30% likely to get into an accident in the next year. There are also other ways of doing this but Machine learning will take data as input and then generate a model (learn) from that data.

Comment: Please add a source to support your answer.

Comment: I guess you can give a few examples of popular AI fields unrelated to ML to substantiate your point of view.  May be Ontologies / Knowledge Representation ?